# URL Parameter breaks Flask template

Tags: python, html, css, flask

I'm working on an html form page using a template which can be found [here](https://colorlib.com/wp/template/contact-form-v4/). The template works as expected, however when I include a URL parameter, the page loses its CSS.

Works:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_form():

return render_template('form.html')
```

Doesn't work:

```
@app.route('/add/<param>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_form(param):

    return render_template('form.html')
```

I've worked with URL parameters in the past and never had this problem, what could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your CSS files are included with relative path f.e.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
```

If there is no lead slash then files are relative to the given path.

In the first case, it will be relative to `/` (last part omitted) 
in the second case, it will be relative to `/add/`.

Try change path from above to

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
```

with a leading slash.